# Laravel Eloquent: n+1 accessing related model via accessor

Tags: php, orm, laravel, eloquent

I am having problems with abstracting a model dependency in Laravel.

I have a `Metal` model and a `Fix` model. A Metal has many Fixes, but when I query the Metal model, I need an attribute on the Metal model which is dependent on a specific associated fix.

I do this using an accessor which queries the fix model from within the Metal Model.

Example below:

```
class Metal extends Eloquent
{
  protected $table = 'metals';

  public function fixes()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('Fix');
  }

  public function getFixAttribute()
  {
    $fix = Fix::where('metal_id', $this->id)
    ->where('currency_id', Session::get('currency'))->remember(10)->first();

    $amFix = $fix->am;

    return $amFix;
  }

  protected $appends = array('fix');
}
```

Without the `->remember(10)`, each time the Metal model is required, I will end up performing a db query for every row queried in the metal table. `n+1` problem.

example - assuming that there are 10 metals in the database, `dd(Metal::all());` will query the metals table, then the fixes table 10 times to get the fix attribute for each metal.

Further, I don't need the fixAttribute every time, but i will need it quite often - which is why I am appending the attribute accessor.

What is the best way of tackling this problem? Can anybody point me into the right direction?

Ideally, I want to query the fixes table once giving me one fix for each metal, then match up the metal_id's with the metals table and use that in the metals fix accessor.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent?/docs/eloquent/#eager-loading) (`Eager Load Constraints`) to reduce the `n+ query problem` using `with` method:

```
$metalsWithFixes = Metal::with(array('fixes' => function($q){
    $q->where('currency_id', Session::get('currency'));
}))->get();
```

**Update:** You can use the relationship as `$metalsWithFixes->first()->fixes` and can select fields from `fix` tablw but the relation key (`metal_id`) must be present in the select `array`:

```
$metalsWithFixes = Metal::with(array('fixes' => function($q){
    $q->where('currency_id', Session::get('currency'))->select(array('metal_id', 'am'));
}))->get();
```

You can use a `loop` in your `view (blade)` as:

```
@foreach($metalsWithFixes as $metal)

    {{ $metal->fieldName }}

    @foreach($metalWithFix->fixes as $fix)
        {{ $fix->am }}
    @endforeach;

@endforeach
```

Since, it's a `one-to-many` relationship so the `$metal->fixes` will return more than one `fix` or one (if there is only one) but as an `array`.

Comment: That's great, thanks but is it not possible to make that an accessor on the `Metal` model so that I can just query `$metal->fix`? The only attribute from the fix table which would be required is `am` as above.